# Dataframe.max() giving all NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max, nan

I have a pandas DataFrame with data that looks like this:

[image]

With the data extending beyond what you can see here. I can't tell if the blue cells hold numeric or string data, but it should be numeric, since I transformed them to those values with multiplication. But I don't know pandas well enough to be sure.

Anyway, I call `.max(axis=1)` on this dataframe, and it gives me this:

[image]

As far as I know, there are no empty cells or cells with weird data. So why am I getting all `nan`?

Comment: Can you share `df.count()` and `df.dtypes`?

Comment: You can check the `dtypes` of the columns. If it is `object`, this means that it has `strings`. Also check `df['col'].isna().any()`. This would be `True` even if one row has `nan`.

Comment: @Zero @Mayank Porwal it was strings. It didn't seem to find any bad numbers with the isna() check (but seeing that I had to check just under a hundred columns, I may have missed one), but when I ran @jezrael 's `astype()`, it failed saying it couldn't convert an empty string, so there's one *somewhere*. But `to_numeric()` with `coerce` seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert all values to numeric by [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
df = df.astype(float)
```

If not working, use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for `NaN`s if not numeric values:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

And then count `max`:

```
print (df.max(axis=1))
```